# Best way to show User Profile?

Tags: website-design, html

I'm working on a web application where I have to save a user's info. This form has about 20 fields. This is the format I am currently using:
[image: Detail Form]

**Problem:**

What's the best way to show these fields in a way that any other person on the web can see this profile in less time.

Comment: In what context are you using the form? Also, I cannot see the entire form in the image you've attached. You can post an external link if you want, rather than attaching the image in the post.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question.. Are you looking to design the look/feel of your form now or how people will view it after that data has been provided.

Comment: @CourtneyJordan Yes you are right,I want how people will view it after that data has been provided.

Comment: @rk.Here i am showing some fields of the form just for e.g.

Answer (score 6):

One nice way is to visually group related items under categories, i.e.,

'Contact Info' => [First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Phone]
'Work Info' => [Current Title, Specialization, etc.]

You can see an example of this with [Stack Exchange user profiles](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/27280/joshua-barron), or the example below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRV0NJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this idea but this format again make the form lengthy :-(

Comment: True, the form will be lengthy, but the user will be able to visually navigate to whatever information is relevant to them in an efficient manner.  The only way to compress the length of the page is to hide information or transform your presentation of it, i.e., figure out a way to change this text into a pictorial representation or something.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of a wide question to ask, but I'll do my best to answer. User Profiles can be boring, and somewhat displaying information in unnecessary dull lists. This has been the case for many years, until we got social media.

Yes, I know, Social Media isn't the answer to everything - but in the case of presenting *my profile* thay have made a huge difference. Take a look at any profile page of twitter, facebook or Google+ and you see no boring list (Ok - there are some, but much fewer than before).

My personal favorite is foursquares profile page. Everything is there, packed with data - and still nice to view, easy to grasp - most important first, and so on. If you want to dig into (drill down) to the information - you can.

Take a look at foursquare profile page - and go all in "share with joy, steal with pride"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful concept.I am working on this and i will update you asap :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was also working on such a form with quite a lot of text fields and thus making it an extensive form. This was my solution to it:[image]

just imagine your textfields within each dropdown.
Hoping this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Show things that of most immediate interest or have the most concise details first. Usually people don't have time to look at everything, so if you provide chunks of information they can digest easily, they will then be able to look at things in more detail if they want to. By hiding some of this content (e.g. have a 'more...' or some switcher to expand or collapse sections) you are doing yourself and the user a favour by letting them decide what they want to see and what is important for them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a Design question than a UX question.

From a UX standpoint, the page design should serve what users are trying to accomplish on your app and respect the IA, UIUX they experienced so far (on previous page).

From a data perspective, it would make sense to create a relation between the data and its representation. For instance you could present all "User identity" fields as a business card, use a map to show locations -although it might be a pain to implement, etc.

Comment: It's both a UX and Design question. Design can impact the users experience which I delightfully encounter on a day to day basis. If a page/website is poorly designed then a user can have a negative experience. Yale's Art Department(http://art.yale.edu/) is a good example of poor design and a huge deciding factor in my college education.